# automatically css/js content in 1 file

Tags: javascript, php, css

I separate many CSS/JS so it's easier to work in and look over.
But when the website loads, it has to load all those JS and CSS files and that will extend the loading times more and more.

So I was trying to put a simple php script in my website that takes all the CSS content and put it in 1 file. Same goes for the JS content.

It looks like this ($data['js'] and $data['css'] are arrays with all the files):

```
<?php
    $jsData = "";
    $cssData = "";
    foreach($data['js'] as $js) {
        $jsData .= file_get_contents($js);
    }
    foreach($data['css'] as $css) {
        $cssData .= file_get_contents($css);
    }
    file_put_contents('static/js/javascript.js', $jsData);
    file_put_contents('static/css/style.css', $cssData);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/javascript.js"></script>
<link href="static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

As I'm still a beginner I wanted to ask you for tips/suggestions,
What do you guys think?

Thank you

Comment: you're trying to minify your files . for css it should be fine but for javascript you could face issues. for instance , the order of files should be maintained, you should make sure files are properly delimited to avoid overlapping of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this [CssJsBundler](https://github.com/subchild/JavaScript-and-CSS-Bundler)

The above is on github, and opensource and it does what you have requested !

And also check out http://www.subchild.com/2008/08/07/simple-javascript-and-css-file-bundler/

which tells you how to configure the options.

Comment: Haven't seen this one coming by, Thank you very much!